# Nodejs CPU intensive tasks

Tags: node.js

recently started to develop with node and ran into a problem. I have a web service which is a raw bank. basically a collection of raw files (photography stuff). Users just upload them and download. nothing fancy. But recently i came up with an idea to add sorting feature which depends on camera settings: shutter speed, geolocation, fstop, colors and etc. basically upon uploading a raw file I need to process it and this is very heavy files, roughly 60-150 MB each and usually user uploads 3-4 files. what would be the best solution to process heavy files without actually harming server performance.

Comment: I don't believe there is a great way to handle doing what you are asking.  Unless the files are formatted in a way such that you can simply pull out the data via a key in a hash table or something (which is a O(1) because it's a direct look up) you are going to have to process the data and do whatever you want. That being said, you could write some highly specialized C++ code or some other low level code that is optimized to your specific task but ultimate if you have to process large amounts of data, you need power in the form of memory and processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of things to consider here:

- Do you have a good work-queue solution to prioritize jobs and fan them out across multiple worker processes?
- Do you make use of things like [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to make each process much more productive on multi-core systems?
- Do you use compiled libraries to help process the images faster? As KolCrooks says, GPU-accelerated libraries are a huge asset as they can cut processing time down from minutes to fractions of a second. This is only relevant if your server has adequate GPU resources, "built-in" GPUs rarely suffice.
- How are you storing and exchanging these images? What network topology can you use? 10Gbit vs. 1GBit could make a huge difference here.

Comment: I know there are web workers for browsers, cant find it in nodejs docs. and sadly i have no GPU on my server. And question regarding worker threads in node, i thought there no way to access them except writing a c++ addon for it ?

Comment: There's an [NPM package that implements them](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) for Node.js. If you don't have a GPU that's your #1 problem when processing images. I know of one startup that bought a bunch of Mac Pro machines because Core Image (macOS) and GPU acceleration cut their workflow down from seconds per image to basically milliseconds, Core Image can work real-time at 60FPS. Don't underestimate what a GPU can do for you. Cloud-based GPU instances, or on-premise solutions are worth investigating here.

Comment: then  #1 this is to consider optimizing the process itself, if it comes down to milliseconds then a little event loop block won't be a problem

Comment: Precisely. Try using GPU-accelerated libraries. There are many you can easily link in via FFI to Node directly, NVidia and AMD both make and support a variety of projects, plus consider what Apple's Core Image can do, it's *extremely* fast.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing the raw calculations yourself you could look into GPU accelerating them. The best library currently out there for that is https://gpu.rocks/. If you haven't already also make your server work asynchronously and even try making the it with node's cluster feature (the closest you can get to multi-threading in js).

Comment: well there is not much calculation except Demosaicing/debayering the image. it is more of a heavy I/O to handle such as fs, db, saving to remote storages.

Comment: I/O is not usually a big deal as a modern NVMe SSD can handle 2GB/s or more. On the other hand, CPU processing large images is brutally slow compared to the GPU.